# Design of generic test class that calls specific method before and after class - for integration test

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

I want to write a generic test class for special kind of integration test. The generic class has to setup a server before all test in a subclass and tear down after all tests. Each subclass has to provide one string parameter to setup the server.

My problem is to find a good design for it. Since @Before/AfterClass are static the given parameter must be static to. Setting the parameter in constructor of subclass is too late.

I also thought about creating a custom test runner and a custom annotation to set the parameter - but that's probably too much for now?!

**Edit**:

Because of kind of setup it is essential that setup and tear down is only called once per test class - not for every test.

My Stack is Camel + Guice (Standalone app)

Comment: Do you have Sping in your stack? If yes, you may be interested in its @ContextConfiguration annotation.

Comment: Within each subclass, does the string that it needs to provide to setup the server ever change or is it always the same?

Comment: it is the same per class - for all tests in this class.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use a [Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules), in particular perhaps the [ExternalResources](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#externalresource-rules) ones.

By using a [ClassRule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#classrule) and runner you should be able to instantiate normal objects and avoid the static methods, but have sub-classes instantiate their own / customised rules to set up your server as required.

Comment: thanks by i need the server setup and tear down time only once for all tests in a class not for each test.

Comment: but how to give a different parameter? If i map this to example given in ClassRule's doc: i would need to give one different parameter to connect to the server per test class. In my case the server is running all the time but i need to prepare it per test - send something testspecific